# Bxslider pause Video after Switching Slides

Tags: javascript, html, bxslider

I know this Topic has already been discussed here but there seems to be an error with my code which won't stop the video playing in the Bxslider but rather reload the whole page.

```
<ul class="headslider">             
    <li class="youtube-player cf">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li class="youtube-player cf">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KzJtBr6Yxg?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li class="youtube-player cf">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LNEYhwAp7nQ?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.headslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: false,
        speed: 1150,
        pause: 5000,
        pager: false,
        onSlideBefore: function() {
          $('.youtube-player').find('iframe').each(function() {
            this.pause();
          });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish and I'm pretty new to Javascript. That said from the looks of it you need to call the YouTube API property.

You can view the API reference: 
[Youtube API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

In this example I added ID's to your iframes (you could also use div's instead according to YouTube). It's probably recommended to use divs and let Youtube API create the iframes.

The Youtube API will call bxslider after it loads. I have the first Video playing by default and then every time you slide over the videos will be paused and then only the current one will play.

You could also pause / resume videos by referencing the YT.Player object.

```
<ul class="headslider">             
<li class="youtube-player cf">
    <iframe id="video1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
</li>
<li class="youtube-player cf">
    <iframe id="video2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KzJtBr6Yxg?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
</li>
<li class="youtube-player cf">
    <iframe id="video3" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LNEYhwAp7nQ?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
</li>
</ul>

<script>
var player;
var player2;
var player3;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video1', {
        videoId: 'E5ln4uR4TwQ',
        events: {
            onReady: playVideo
        }
    });
        player2 = new YT.Player('video2', {
        videoId: '6KzJtBr6Yxg',
    });
        player3 = new YT.Player('video3', {
        videoId: 'LNEYhwAp7nQ',
    });
    callbxSlider();
}

function playVideo(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function callbxSlider() {
$('.headslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: false,
        speed: 1150,
        pause: 5000,
        pager: false,
        onSlideBefore: function(element) {
            newVideo = element["0"].childNodes[1]; // capture current iframe
            player.pauseVideo();
            player2.pauseVideo();
            player3.pauseVideo();

            switch (newVideo.id) {
                case "video1": player.playVideo();
                break; 
                case "video2": player2.playVideo();
                break; 
                case "video3": player3.playVideo();
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```